# Top Item On Combo Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `windows forms` project and List of type `DateTime` which I want to bind in `combobox`. I want on top of the combo box to have text `All`. How to do that ?

```
List<DateTime> dueDates = manager.GetUniqueDueDates();
cbDates.DataSource = dueDates;
```

For example

```
All
1/1/2001
1/1/2002
1/1/2003
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to add it to your datasource as a first element

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Insert method of the items property to add the extra item.

```
cbDates.Items.Insert(0, "All");
```

This way your datasource does not need to be a list of string.

**Update**

As mentioned by @Hassan Nisar in the comments, it won't work if you bind the datasource, but you can add items using a loop(refer to @Hassan Nisar's answer for an example).

Comment: Is it working after you bind combobox with a datasource?

Comment: I am getting Argument Exception `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.`

Comment: @HassanNisar Yes, you're right, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I checked it there was not such a problem. You may have set the datasource somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After binding with `List<DateTime>` you cannot insert item.

Argument exception will be raised **`Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.`**

Skip binding with data source and add items by iterating through list:

```
List<DateTime> dueDates = manager.GetUniqueDueDates();
//cbDates.DataSource = dueDates;

foreach (var date in dueDates)
     cbDates.Items.Add(date)

cbDates.Items.Insert(0, "All");
```

Comment: I did this but I get Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set. I didn't set the datasource property.

Comment: Use `foreach` loop as mentioned in the answer. Don't bind combobox with a datasource. Just iterate over the list. Make sure you clear previous items before adding items repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the list of dueDtes as string because "All" is string we cant add in Datetime list.

```
List<string> dueDates = manager.GetUniqueDueDates();
```

in GetUniqueDueDates function you need to add "All"

```
public List<string> GetUniqueDueDates()
{
List<string> uniqueDate=new List<string>();
uniqueDate.add("All");

//Rest of your code


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is of type DateTime , you should first make it to List to make it work when you add "All"

```
List<string> dueDates = new List<string>();
dueDates.Add("All");
dueDates.Add(new DateTime(2001,03,01).ToString());
dueDates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 04, 01).ToString());
dueDates.Add(new DateTime(2003, 05, 01).ToString());
cbDates.DataSource = dueDates;
```

Comment: of type `DateTime` (typo), it may also be worth keeping the source as `object` so you could always just use `Items.OfType<DateTime>()` to re-retrieve the dates

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort all items after adding another 1 since its all **dateTime** after *All* .
Something like:

e.g: *a* was suppose to be your **dataSource**:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(a.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
```

and property to true before anything else:

```
comboBox1.Sorted = true;
```